# Уведомление или пояснение?

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, конкурс

В [истории ревизий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/647023/revisions) видно такой текст:

> [image: ревизии]

Нужно его "сделать красиво". Т.е. выбор между "уведомление" и "пояснение" лишь часть проблемы.

Связанные с проблемой строки:

- > [Notice removed / Уведомление было удалено](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262654?key=33f86a7c39bdd877d510ae599c73f3e0)
- > [notice removed / уведомление было удалено](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40263664?key=f6b5073bf4859e1b8db3deab8652a71c)
- > [Notice added / Добавлено пояснение](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262686?key=f405d3b22c14a41542de003d857308d5)
- > [Canonical answer required / Необходим чёткий ответ](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262896?key=70f4d8f475df5adc1b89646edacbb502)

Всё это склеивается по формату, заданному в [другой строке](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/40262861?key=07b823322071b472f58c16f7793577d5):

- > **$historyType$** $noticeType$ by $userLink$
- > **$historyType$** $noticeType$ участником $userLink$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Предлагаю "notice" в данном контексте переводить всё же как "пояснение". Итоговый вариант вижу таким:

- > **Удалено пояснение** «Необходим чёткий ответ» участником {UserName}
- > **Добавлено пояснение** «Необходим чёткий ответ» участником {UserName}

Т.е. добавили кавычки-ёлочки и изменили фразу об удалении.

P.S. Утвердил на transifex. Проверяйте вечером в понедельник 10 апреля 2017.

Answer (score 0):

А вот ещё один вариант: **примечание**.

> **Удалено примечание** «Необходим чёткий ответ» участником {UserName}

> **Добавлено примечание** «Необходим чёткий ответ» участником {UserName}

Потому что оно не очень-то *поясняет* содержание сообщения. Оно скорее добавляет эдаких "метаданных" о том, как его следует воспринимать.